# New form variable needs to be available across the whole site

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails site that uses Stripe subscriptions.  I've created a modal that pops up a form that allow users to subscribe if they click on a link in the header.  Since the header is displayed throughout the site, I put the code for the modal in the _header.html.erb file.  My issue is that I don't know where to put the

```
@subscriber = Subscriber.new
```

code so that it is available wherever the user is in the site. I'm getting an ActionView::Template::Error (First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty) from the new subscriber form unless I'm on a view where I've put the Subscriber.new code in that particular controller's action.

Comment: Well, you can put it right there in the modal. It doesn't contain many calculations, just a simple `Subscriber.new`.

Answer (score 2):

A solution that worked was to create this code in application_controller.rb

```
before_action :load_subscriber

def load_subscriber
  @subscriber = Subscriber.new
end
```